# "Куча времени прошлА", "куча времени прошлО" или и то и другое неприемлемо?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Меня уверяют, что надо говорить "куча времени прошлО", а мне кажется, что либо "прошлА", либо вообще так нельзя сказать.

Comment: Данный вопрос отмечен как «низкокачественный» и, видимо, из-за несоответствия заявленной метки стилю фразы. В узком кругу чего только не услышишь. «Огромное количество времени», кстати, совсем не лучше.

Comment: И почему не лучше?

Comment: Это уже другая тема.

Comment: Действительно, "куча времени" бывает только в запасе, она с "прошествием" времени стилистически не сочетается - со всеми скидками на "разговорность". Неформально тратят такую "кучу" (или просто много времени) в форме "уймы".

Comment: Похоже на то, Александр, спасибо!

Comment: Sharon права, что "куча" в значении "много". Оно не звучит здесь как подлежащее, а звучит как наречие. Мне кажется, что его порой употребляют как наречие, в связи с этим и склонять не хочется. "Ни то ни то" с запятой?

Comment: @oleedd: ну да, с запятой.

Comment: А чего? Оно равносильно "ни то ни другое", а выражения такого типа пишутся без запятой.

Comment: @oleedd: не равносильно.

Comment: Равносильно, даже более того, потому что одно слово "то" (а не разные), которое указывает на разные вещи: http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=ни+то+ни+то. И ещё "неприемлемо" необходимо раздельно, потому что не "*ни то ни то есть неприемлемо*", а "*ни то ни то не есть приемлемо*". При "ни" используется двойное отрицание, а не утверждение.

Comment: @oleedd: нет. Так нельзя.

Comment: Как "так"? Вот сейчас, без НИ, уже не надо.

Comment: А вот не надо было запятую перед ИЛИ убирать. С ней можно (и даже лучше — присоединение), только тогда там получается интересная ошибка оформления. Взял и всё испортил. А теперь уже нет смысла о ней говорить, а момент интересный.

Comment: @oleedd: ни фига не лучше. С "ни" нельзя раздельно. И слитно тоже.

Comment: *ни фига не лучше* — смотря с какой стороны, если с той, что ошибка вылазит, то да, а в плане присоединительной интонации — лучше. Почему нельзя раздельно? Похожий пример: *ему не понятно ни то ни то*.

Comment: Так не говорят *(не приемлемо).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разговорный вариант **"куча времени"** часто используется в речи, например: у меня куча времени, на все это уйдет куча времени, тратится (уходит) куча времени, это ж куча времени!

Варианты "куча времени прошло" и "куча времени прошла" встречаются не часто, избегаются по возможности. **С точки зрения грамматики, правильным будет выражение "куча времени прошла**", так как куча ― это существительное со значением большого количества, и это **главное слово** в количественном сочетании, с которым согласуется сказуемое.

Сравнить: До двух часов ещё **оставалась бездна времени**; С той эпохи, когда на Олимпе жили боги, **прошла бездна времени**. Также: Мне **понадобилась пара** минут, еще **пара минут ушла** на то, чтобы выйти к подъезду.

С другой стороны,  выражение "куча времени прошло" может поддерживаться сочетанием "**много времени прошло**".

Сложность выбора подходящего варианта и определяет **низкую частотность** этого сочетания.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Интересно отметить **колебание в согласовании и для сочетания «уйма времени»:** (1) На это **ушла** бы уйма времени и средств! [Валентин Кирсанов. Интерьер и... рекорды // «Техника - молодежи», 1977]

(2) Сорокин нитки стал перегрызать. Уйма времени **ушло.** Девчонки плакали и дрожали. [Г. А. Галахова. Легкий кораблик ― капустный листок (1975)]

Comment: Мне выражение "уйма времени ушло" представляется грубой ошибкой автора: замена близкого по смыслу "много" склоняемым существительным ж. р. "уйма" требует согласования с ним. И стилистически это плохо - в отрыве от того, у кого эта ума ушла: сама по себе она не существует, это человеческая принадлежность - ей располагают и её тратят.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, "прошла". Кучу заменим на уйму — и фразу можно вкладывать в уста хоть изнеженной тургеневской героини.